# Can't add TestNG dependencies required for cucumber

Tags: maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am trying to add required dependencies in pom.xml to run cucumber framework with TestNG. But its failing, please check below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
     <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.5</version>
         <type>pom</type>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Please check it**
[Pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7swcF.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and add more context. Its not clear as to what do you mean when you say `its failing`.

Comment: Please refer screenshot attached for the same.
Please check it Pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 1.2.5 u need to use info.cukes in group id. But u should use the latest version which is 4 using the io.cucumber group id.
Refer this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java. Also use the same version for all cucumber jars.